# How to create a file in winston logger

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I am currently using Winston logger i have a that is there any Winston logger function which helps in creating the log file if the current file is not present for logging?

```
   winston.loggers.add("order_log", {
    transports: [
        new(winston.transports.Console)({
            //name: "order_check_console",  
            level: 'debug',
            //json: true,
            colorize: true
        }),
        new(winston.transports.File)({
            //name: "order_check_file",
            filename: system_path.order_trans_path,
            level: 'debug',
            handleExceptions: true,
            humanReadableUnhandledException: true
        })
    ]
});
```